# Math Calculation not Correct

Tags: java, android, math

Can Somebody please tell me what is wrong.  when I type the equations for low and high into a calculator I get low = 118.129 high = 113.629.
But for some reason both low and high are showing 119.0 when I run the code.

```
match_FRC = 82;//Double.parseDouble(FRC_match_textbox.getText().toString());
match_DTR = 1.455;//Double.parseDouble(DTR_match_textbox.getText().toString());

//math functions 
low = Math.round((match_FRC * match_DTR)/((1/100)+1));
high = Math.round((match_FRC * match_DTR)/((5/100)+1));
```

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of a question about the difference between integer division and real number division, but I haven't been able to find the right question.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan I actually tried to test this in a browser console first (JS has `Math.round` too) and was trying to figure out why I couldn't replicate the fault.  Only then spotted that it was actually Java.  It works in JS because JS doesn't have integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a floating point constant instead of integers, e.g.:

```
low = Math.round((match_FRC * match_DTR)/((1.0 / 100)+1));
```

As it is, your `((1 / 100) + 1)` is an integer expression that evaluates to exactly 1.

Making the `1` into `1.0` (or the `100` into `100.0`) will cause promotion of the other operands (and the expression as a whole) into floating point.

Comment: Thanks that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I is simple like a math!

```
5/100 (Integer) = 0
0 + 1 = 1
82*1.455 = 119.31
119.31 / 1 = 119.31
round ( 119.31 ) = 119
```

just change 100 to 100.0

```
low = Math.round((match_FRC * match_DTR)/((1/100.0)+1));
high = Math.round((match_FRC * match_DTR)/((5/100.0)+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing `Math.round()` into the calculator?

`Math.round()` delivers a `long`, with no fractional part. Your expectatation that `low` will contain a fractioanl part therefore has no basis.